# Matlab function precedence and subfolders

Tags: matlab, function

In the Matlab function precedence [page](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html), it states that function precedence goes:

1. Functions in the current folder.
2. Functions elsewhere on the path, in order of appearance.

My question is, when they say "Functions in the current folder" does this exclude functions in *subfolders* of the current folder? If so, is there a way for me to have subfolders be called preferentially without changing the order of my folders in the path?

I need to do this because I have 2 folders (each with subfolders) of code that run functions with the same name. It seems the subfolders aren't given automatic precedence. I really don't want to have to change my path order every time I run one folder, and I really don't want to have to rename 100s of functions and function calls that my team has written.

The only solution I can think of would be to remove the whole subfolder system and just have a jumbled mess of files in one folder. Are there any other things I can do?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Subfolders are not searched for functions. You should have known this before starting to write code spread out over subfolders. The only searched subfolders are one called `private`, whose functions can only be called by functions in the parent directory, and subfolders that start with `@` where you write overloaded functions. It depends on your code structure (how all these files relate to each other) what solutions you have. Could you show that?

Comment: ok, thank you. Unfortunately, I did not write this code but just have to organise it. If I put an @ in front of subfolders are you saying that this would solve it? That would be a good solution so I'll try that.

Comment: ahh nope, didn't work. So I'm guessing that's not what you meant.

Comment: Why don’t you [edit] your question and include your code structure. Is this a toolbox with many functions being called from outside, or an app with a single entry point?